# Select only the nth largest value in a Series, for each day

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have some noise survey data telling me noise levels measured over the period of several days. I want to find the 5th highest noise level in each night-time period. I have made this into a Pandas Series and used groupby and nlargest methods to show me the 5 highest noise levels each night, but now I want to view only the 5th highest value for each period (i.e. 82, 86, 86, 87 etc.). What's the best way to achieve this?

```
night_time_lmax.groupby(by=night_time_lmax.index.date).nlargest(5)
```

````
            Start date & time  
2021-08-18  2021-08-18 23:00:00     82.0
            2021-08-18 23:15:00     82.0
            2021-08-18 23:30:00     82.0
            2021-08-18 23:45:00     82.0
2021-08-19  2021-08-19 05:45:00    100.0
            2021-08-19 01:15:00     91.0
            2021-08-19 04:45:00     87.0
            2021-08-19 06:15:00     87.0
            2021-08-19 01:45:00     86.0
2021-08-20  2021-08-20 06:30:00     90.0
            2021-08-20 06:00:00     88.0
            2021-08-20 03:15:00     87.0
            2021-08-20 05:30:00     87.0
            2021-08-20 01:15:00     86.0
2021-08-21  2021-08-21 01:30:00     98.0
            2021-08-21 03:00:00     93.0
            2021-08-21 00:45:00     88.0
            2021-08-21 06:00:00     88.0
            2021-08-21 03:30:00     87.0
2021-08-22  2021-08-22 23:45:00    102.0
            2021-08-22 00:30:00     96.0
            2021-08-22 06:30:00     92.0
            2021-08-22 05:00:00     91.0
            2021-08-22 01:30:00     90.0
2021-08-23  2021-08-23 01:15:00     98.0
            2021-08-23 02:15:00     88.0
            2021-08-23 00:45:00     87.0
            2021-08-23 03:00:00     86.0
            2021-08-23 06:00:00     86.0
2021-08-24  2021-08-24 01:00:00     93.0
            2021-08-24 00:30:00     89.0
            2021-08-24 06:30:00     87.0
            2021-08-24 02:45:00     86.0
            2021-08-24 06:00:00     86.0```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options here.

Either sort your data by your value and then take the `nth` element per group:

```
(night_time_lmax.sort_values(by='value_column', ascending=False)
                .groupby(by=night_time_lmax.index.date).nth(5)
)

## below gives the same result for shorter syntax:
# (night_time_lmax.sort_values(by='value_column')
#                 .groupby(by=night_time_lmax.index.date).nth(-5)
# )
```

Or use a double `groupby`, once for the top 5 and once for the last:

```
(night_time_lmax.groupby(by=night_time_lmax.index.date).nlargest(5)
                .groupby(by=night_time_lmax.index.date).last()
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually a series rather than a df, so with a couple of modifications, I eventually got there using your suggestion:
night_time_lmax_sorted = night_time_lmax.sort_values(ascending=False)
night_time_lmax_sorted.groupby(by=night_time_lmax_sorted.index.date).nth(9)